# NaN values in bokeh plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I asked this question on the google group of bokeh earlier [link](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/rqJPB1PN6tw) and learned quite a bit by the helpful answer provided by Sarah Bird, just to post the answer here, for anyone who is encountering something like this. I was using bokeh 0.9.2 then.

I was trying to build a bubble chart for a batch of commercial leases where:

1. x axis represent the date the lease will end (Datetime: 2015 - 2020)
2. y axis represent the rent level (Float: 200- 500)
3. size / radius of the circles represent the size of the premise (Float: 200 - 8,000 - GFA)
4. color of the circle represent the floor # (Integer: 1 - 40)

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from datetime import datetime
output_notebook()

PATH = ''
filename = 'test_RR.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(PATH + filename)

df['TA_END'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['ET Date']), df.L_END, np.where(df['ET Date'] < df.L_END, df['ET Date'], df.L_END)) # just some data cleaning, don't bother with this

GFA_SCALE_FACTOR = 2
df['GFA_radius'] = np.sqrt( df.GFA / np.pi ) * GFA_SCALE_FACTOR

import seaborn as sns
colors = list(sns.cubehelix_palette(28, start=.5, rot=-.75))
hex_colors = np.array(['#%02x%02x%02x' % (c[0]*255, c[1]*255, c[2]*255) for c in colors])
df['color'] = hex_colors[df.FL - 4]
```

An error occurred when I was trying:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", width = 800, height = 400)

p.circle(x='TA_END', y='Eff Rent', 
         size= 'GFA_radius',
         fill_alpha=0.8, line_width=0.5, line_alpha=0.5, color = 'color', source = source)
show(p)
```

Error message led me to think there was something wrong with the way datetime was serialized:

```
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

I shall post Sarah's answer in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, it turns out was actually because of an NaN value in the column of "ET Date" of the DataFrame "df", which although is irrelevant to the plot, caused bokeh's serialization to fail.

so if I just do:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df[['TA_END', 'Eff Rent', 'GFA_radius', 'color']])
```

Everything would work out.

A good tip is always only make a ColumnDataSource from the columns you need because then you're using up more data / processing power in the
browser than you need to - also from Sarah.

However, I do hope bokeh can handle some NaN data, as some plots may want to show an empty slot now and then.

Comment: Any update on this? Has bokeh been able to handle NaN values ?

Comment: My experience is that if you want to pass `float("nan")` to bokeh, instead pass the string `"NaN"`, which is the javascript stringification of NaN.